# transmission-daemon possible uploading bug?

Tags: linux, transmission

I'm wrecking my brains since a week ago with a problem with transmission daemon in my Raspberry Pi 2B. I tried to set my uploading speed to 1kb/s but it seems that it does not work correctly. I have all my torrents downloaded but if I hold the transmission opened I noticed (using the system monitor) that the system is uploading data up to 20 kb/s: When I close the transmission-daemon process the uploading chart decreases to 0 and when I launch another time the transmission-daemon process it keeps uploading data... I paste below my /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json configuration file content:

```
"alt-speed-down": 50, 
"alt-speed-enabled": false, 
"alt-speed-time-begin": 540, 
"alt-speed-time-day": 127, 
"alt-speed-time-enabled": false, 
"alt-speed-time-end": 1020, 
"alt-speed-up": 1, 
"bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0", 
"bind-address-ipv6": "::", 
"blocklist-enabled": false, 
"blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist", 
"cache-size-mb": 4, 
"dht-enabled": true, 
"download-dir": "/chroots/wheezy-armel/home/odroid/Storage/torrent/finished", 
"download-limit": 800, 
"download-limit-enabled": 0, 
"download-queue-enabled": true, 
"download-queue-size": 11, 
"encryption": 1, 
"idle-seeding-limit": 1, 
"idle-seeding-limit-enabled": true, 
"incomplete-dir": "/chroots/wheezy-armel/home/odroid/Storage/torrent/.temp", 
"incomplete-dir-enabled": true, 
"lpd-enabled": false, 
"max-peers-global": 200, 
"message-level": 2, 
"peer-congestion-algorithm": "", 
"peer-id-ttl-hours": 6, 
"peer-limit-global": 200, 
"peer-limit-per-torrent": 50, 
"peer-port": 51413, 
"peer-port-random-high": 65535, 
"peer-port-random-low": 49152, 
"peer-port-random-on-start": false, 
"peer-socket-tos": "default", 
"pex-enabled": true, 
"port-forwarding-enabled": false, 
"preallocation": 1, 
"prefetch-enabled": 1, 
"queue-stalled-enabled": true, 
"queue-stalled-minutes": 30, 
"ratio-limit": 2, 
"ratio-limit-enabled": false, 
"rename-partial-files": true, 
"rpc-authentication-required": true, 
"rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0", 
"rpc-enabled": true, 
"rpc-password": "{8e6303ef3e646a5885c967cc1c3d6243965ea0687yF2.NcH", 
"rpc-port": 9091, 
"rpc-url": "/transmission/", 
"rpc-username": "transmission", 
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1", 
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": false, 
"scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true, 
"script-torrent-done-enabled": false, 
"script-torrent-done-filename": "", 
"seed-queue-enabled": false, 
"seed-queue-size": 10, 
"speed-limit-down": 100, 
"speed-limit-down-enabled": false, 
"speed-limit-up": 1, 
"speed-limit-up-enabled": true, 
"start-added-torrents": true, 
"trash-original-torrent-files": false, 
"umask": 0, 
"upload-limit": 1, 
"upload-limit-enabled": true, 
"upload-slots-per-torrent": 1, 
"utp-enabled": true
enter code here
```

Can anybody help me please? I don't know what to do...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Randomly stumbled on your post. Make sure you 'sudo service transmission-daemon stop' before editing the config file. Then 'sudo service transmission-daemon start' once you're finished editing. If you don't do this, transmission ignores and writes over your edits when you close the config document.